# Which POSTFIX configuration for sending from localhost?

Tags: php, email, localhost, postfix-mta

I am in the process of configuring POSTFIX for use of mail() function in php.  I only want to send emails from localhost, and I am NOT interested in receiving emails.  This is for testing only.

My POSTFIX configuration choices are:

1. No configuration
2. Internet Site
3. Internet with smarthost
4. Satellite system
5. Local only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Internet Site` when you have a static ip address with reverse dns pointing to the hostname of your server.

Otherwise use `Internet with smarthost` and relay using your providers smtp server...